# Django hide slug field to users in custom template

Tags: python, django

I've built a form with auto-generating slug field with short js code.
I'd want to hide the slug field to user to prevent them being edited.

```
//slugify.js

const titleInput = document.querySelector('input[name=title');
const slugInput = document.querySelector('input[name=slug]');

const slugify = (val) => {
    return val.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
        .replace(/&/g, '-and-') // replacing & with '-and-'
        .replace(/[\s\W-]+/g, '-') //replcaing spaces, non-word chars and dashes with a single '-'
};

titleInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    slugInput.setAttribute('value', slugify(titleInput.value));
});
```

```
//models.py
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique = True)
```

as I remove it from `forms.py`, slugfield becomes blank. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how should I fix it.
I've tried removing the slugfield from `forms.py`, but it would just does not add the slug, because I targeted the slug with the input in `slugify.js`.

I've tried `editable = False` on slugField, but it would give me an error

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'slug' cannot be specified for VideoPost model form as it is a non-editable field`

Would there be any other way that I could hide slugfield from the form and properly save the slug as well?

Comment: You could use the `HiddenInput` widget for your slug field to hide it from the user but still have it in the html

Answer (score 0):

Do your slug generation on the back-end! Front-end code can be edited in the browser, you anyone can temper with the slug name.

Make your slug field Blank=True, Null=True, and just populate if when it's getting saved.